# Dockerfile FROM directive using the same tag

Tags: dockerfile

I have the following docker hierarchy

a/Dockerfile:

```
FROM alpine:3.4
```

b/Dockerfile:

```
FROM a:1
RUN somethingB
```

And here is the build commands:

```
docker build -t a:1 a
docker build -t b:1 b
```

I would like the tags of a and b to always be in-sync (it would actually be `git rev-parse HEAD`) for each build. Is it possible doing this without "sed"ing B/Dockerfile before each build and changing `FROM a:1` to `FROM a:2` before calling `docker build -t b:2 b`?

The reason I am going through all this trouble is that:

- There are multiple builds of the same git repo running in parallel against the same docker host, but each with a different HEAD (tag)
- b:1 has a sister docker (c:1) which also depends on a:1 (so I cannot simply merge a and b to the same dockerfile

Comment: I don't think this is possible without first processing the `Dockerfile` with sed or some templating language. I've run into this problem as well and couldn't find a native solution. There are probably some community build tools that will solve the problem.